# JQuery, GreaseMonkey, onSubmit redirection

Tags: jquery, redirect, greasemonkey, preventdefault, onsubmit

I'm trying to make a redirection instead of submiting a form with a GreaseMonkey plugin, so here is my code :

```
    $(input).closest("form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        q = $(this).find(input).val();
        if(k = getBang(q, bangs)) {
            window.location.href = bangs[k]+q.replace('!'+k, '');
            console.log(bangs[k]+q.replace('!'+k, ''));
        }
         return false;
    });
```

So the e.preventDefault() do not work well, and the redirection is not happening.
The console.log show me the correct link to redirect to, bug i don't understand why it don't occur.

This script is executed on https://startpage.com/

Do you think that it enter in conflict with a JavaScript on the page itself?

Comment: What your `console.log()` says?

Comment: Also post full code, where is code of `getBang()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the action attr:

```
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849965/jquery-greasemonkey-onsubmit-redirection";
$('#search_form').attr("action", url);
```